# Amazon LightSail 403 Error from Root account

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, http-status-code-403, amazon-lightsail

I am getting 403 error from Amazon LightSail. I have tried Root account and IAM account, but had no luck.
[image: AWS LightSail 403 error]

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is your account part of AWS Organization?

Comment: @Marcin no it's my personal account